# Should I pickle primes in Python to produce primorials?

Tags: python, pickle, primes

I produced an algorithm in Python to sieve the first n primes, then list the ordered pairs of the index n and the nth primorial p_n#.

Next I evaluate a function based on n and p_n# and finally, the objective, to determine whether the function f(n,p_n#) is monotonic, so the algorithm assesses where the sequence changes from rising to falling and vice-versa.  The code is listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914850) for what it's worth.

This is of course memory-intensive and my pc can only cope with numbers up to around 2,000,000.

At any given point all I actually need is f(n-1), the ordered pair n,p_n#, the prime p_n (in order to quickly find the next prime), and a boolean indicating whether the sequence most recently rose or fell.

> What are the best approaches to avoid storing a hundred thousand or more primes and primorials in memory while preserving speed?

I thought a first step would be to make a sieve that finds the one next prime above some given prime rather than every prime below some maximum.  Then I can evaluate the next value of the function.

But I also wondered if it would be better to sieve batches of say 100 primes at a time.  This could be supported by some "perpetual list" of ordered triples [n,p_n,p_n#] only containing n=100,200,300,... which I generate before runtime.  Searching, I found the concept of "pickling" a list and wondered if this is the right scenario in which to use it, or is there a better way?

Comment: Your link goes to the math.stackexchange.com question list rather than wherever it was supposed to go.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, should be fixed now.

Comment: You might want to just [download a list of primes](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/) instead of generating them yourself. The primorials are a bigger problem. Looking at the post you linked, you seem to be gathering them all in a list, which is going to waste a ton of memory - this seems like a perfect case for a generator (or for a proof instead of brute force, but the proof is more of an issue for the math site). Getting a better int implementation would also help - Python's built-in bignum math isn't anywhere near as optimized as something like gmpy2.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks. I thought the numpy library I linked had a better integer implementation? For the primorials, my idea is just to perpetually store one in a hundred or one in a thousand, then the ones in-between can be calculated.

Comment: numpy only supports fixed size integer up to 64 bits. I don't know if this is enough here.

Comment: It's better for the kind of task it was designed for, but it doesn't do arbitrary-precision arithmetic. Looking again, though, you should almost certainly be adding logarithms instead of multiplying integers.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm starting to wonder now if silent rounding error from INT or INT64 is giving me incorrect results